# Page load Overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, overlay

I have a site that I would like for new users to see a contact us when the page loads. I have tried numerous methods and gotten an overlay but the ability to hide and continue onto the page is not working.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#overlay').fadeIn();
    });
    $('button').click(function() {
      $('#overlay').fadeOut(200, "linear");
    });
     function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
    }

    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
   <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
     <h1>Text</h1>
     <button>hide</button>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If any suggestions for closing the popup exist please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to hide an element, being the most common one to set

```
document.getElementById("myNav").style.display = "none";
```

And to show it again

```
// Empty to have the one specified by CSS or the element default.
// Or "block", "inline", "inline-block"... Whatever fits you better.
document.getElementById("myNav").style.display = "";
```

If you hide by height (is a good decision if you have a CSS transision, but you need fixed heights), you need to set the element overflow to hidden. By default, if the content of an element is bigger than the element size it will be shown, so your `.overlay` class should have `overflow: hidden` to hide it.

By the way, you are using dynamic heights so you are not using transitions. As a recommendation, use the `display` way instead.

EDIT: Just noticed [the ID problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45319095/page-load-overlay/45319199#45319199) that @Rubenxfd points out. He is right. Is going to be the main problem for sure.

Also, another problem you have is that you run this code

```
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#overlay').fadeOut(200, "linear");
});
```

before the button element is rendered, so the event won't attach to it as it don't exists. You should attach it when the page is ready, so you have to move it inside the `ready` function, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myNav').fadeIn();
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('#myNav').fadeOut(200, "linear");
  });
});
```

Notice the difference.

Comment: fixing the overlay class and adding the ready function fixed the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are using an `class`, but calling an `id` in your jQuery.

Change your jQuery to this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.overlay').fadeIn();
    });
    $('button').click(function() {
      $('.overlay').fadeOut(200, "linear");
    });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e2o9jzrv/)

Answer (score 0):

You had a `#` instead of a `.`.
`$('#overlay').fadeOut(200, "linear");` will happen to the element with the id `overlay` not to the class. if you write `$('.overlay').fadeOut(200, "linear");`it will happen to all elements with the class of overlay

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.overlay').fadeIn();
    });
    $('button').click(function() {
      $('.overlay').fadeOut(200, "linear");
    });
     function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
    }

    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
   <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
     <h1>Text</h1>
     <button>hide</button>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which comment??

Comment: Sorry I deleted it because there where too much formatting errors because CTRL + K is not available in the comment box.

Comment: Ok, someone ninjadownvoted it without explaining nothing when is actually a good answer. Going to +1 it to counteract it. Hate ninja downvoters :-/

Comment: I think it was because i was referring to a deleted comment but anyway I edited it now so there is no mislead. Ok I appreciate that :)